# How to load a web page in CordovaWebView for Android?

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

I'm trying to figure out how to open an external link inside a cordova web view without the "InAppBrowser" or system browser.

Initially I've tried to directly pass a link to the web view, blank page.
So I've put an iframe in a local html file, it only opens local files.

Then I tried to use:

```
 window.open(myUrl, '_self');
```

He keeps opening this link in the "InAppBrowser", even if the whitelist doesn't exist, since I've put this:

```
     <access origin="*"/>
```

in the config.xml file.

I have no more ideas. Please, give me some...
By the way I'm using the latest cordova.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to put this line before the initialization of the web view

```
        Config.init(this);
```

They need to clear their code a little bit, or at least update their docs.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location.href=""

or

`<a href="[your External Link]">External Link</a>`.